# Angular 17 - ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError thrown despite calling detectChanges

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-changedetection, change-detector-ref

I'm experiencing a slight issue with Angular and its change detection. I've got a very simple form that allows for additional input containers to be added. Yet, every time I click the add button I get an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` thrown in the console.
When using a standard ngFor the error is thrown in the console, but the new input is still displayed.
However, when using Angular's new `@for` option I get the error thrown in the console, but it also isn't displayed.
In both scenarios, I made sure to call a `detectChanges` (I also tried `markForCheck`), but it made no difference.

```
public properties: Map<number, string> = new Map<number, string>();

public addProperty() {
  const id: number = this.properties.size ?
    Array.from(this.properties.keys()).reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b) + 1 : 1;

  this.properties.set(id, 'placeholder');
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addProperty()">+</button>

<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let attribute of properties.entries()">
    <span>{{ attribute[0] }}</span>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

I'd greatly appreciate any insight into the issue, thanks in advance.

I've tried using both a `ngFor` and Angular's new `@for` option, the only difference between the two is that when using the `@for` the new data isn't displayed in addition to the console error.
I've also attempted calling the change detector manually but it had no impact.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `ng version` ?

Comment: `setTimeout(() => this.properties.set(id, ...))` usually fixes that

Answer (score 1):

Angular `ngFor` is designed for arrays in particular, so I guess change detection is getting confused due to map store by reference. You can convert it into an array before inputing to the `ngFor` which also gets rid of the change detection issue. Please find below a working example!

You can so access the `properties.keys()` or `properties.values()` if you specifically need just the key or the value!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addProperty()">+</button>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      {{properties.entries() | json}}
      <ng-container *ngFor="let attribute of mapEntriesToArray;trackBy: trackByFn ">
        <span>{{ attribute[0] }}</span>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  public properties: Map<number, string> = new Map<number, string>();

  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  get mapEntriesToArray() {
    return Array.from(this.properties.entries());
  }

  public addProperty() {
    const id: number = this.properties.size
      ? Array.from(this.properties.keys()).reduce((a, b) => (a > b ? a : b)) + 1
      : 1;

    this.properties.set(id, 'placeholder');
  }

  trackByFn(index: number, item: any) {
    return index;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pfjjjs)